# how to save array outputs inside variables in php

Tags: php, api, curl

I have this array output :

```
{"NoID":5645656956,"dispositionMessage":"ISSUED","binarySecurityToken":"TUlJQ1VEQ0NBZldnQXdJQkFnSUdBWVBDdjV4OE1Bb0dDQ3FHU000OUJBTUNNQlV4RXpBUkJnTlZCQU1NQ21WSmJuWnZhV05wYm1jd==","number":"1234568","errors":null}
```

and want to save these array outputs inside these variables:

```
$NoID = 5645656956;
$binarySecurityToken = TUlJQ1VEQ0NBZldnQXdJQkFnSUdBWVBDdjV4OE1Bb0dDQ3FHU000OUJBTUNNQlV4RXpBUkJnTlZCQU1NQ21WSmJuWnZhV05wYm1jd==;
$number = 1234568;
```

Thanks for all

Comment: This is not a PHP array, it is a JSON array.

Comment: @MarkusZeller you are right this json output I have it in PHP and want to save the array values inside variables in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the string into an array or object. Then you can access all the properties.

```
$jsonString = '{"NoID":5645656956,"dispositionMessage":"ISSUED","binarySecurityToken":"TUlJQ1VEQ0NBZldnQXdJQkFnSUdBWVBDdjV4OE1Bb0dDQ3FHU000OUJBTUNNQlV4RXpBUkJnTlZCQU1NQ21WSmJuWnZhV05wYm1jd==","number":"1234568","errors":null}';
$json = json_decode($jsonString);

$noId = $json->NoID;
$binarySecurityToken = $json->binarySecurityToken;
$number = $json->number;
```